# What is the difference between Apps and Pages in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, web-applications

When to use which? They look the same when I click on either from their directory other than being named differently.

Comment: This question probably belongs on webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Applications **have** pages to describe them, make fans (the act of liking the application) these pages are just profiles to the application.
- Applications also can have canvas pages, these aren't actually facebook pages...these are the landing pages for your application hosted on ***your*** server. Mainly you'll be asked to install the application (game) before accessing it.
- Applications can be added to pages and users.

Answer (score 1):

A page is a simple thing that displays information about something.

An app is something that can be installed and is more complicated and can run code as per the Facebook API.

Applications are things like games and quizzes.
Pages are for the "fans" of businesses, musicians, actors, etc.

All the information about apps: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Comment: I'm looking at the applications from http://www.facebook.com/directory/applications/... they look the same as pages... no? Moreover, can applications (whatever is more complicated) be added to tabs on pages or applications?

Comment: Click on the "go to app" button when you go to an actual app page - Thats the app. Only certain apps can be added to pages as tabs.

Comment: Where is that button on say here - http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=152263863091#!/apps/application.php?id=152263863091&v=wall

Comment: See "add to my page" on the left. Its something you can add to a page.

Comment: So the difference is apps can be added to (pages and apps) and pages can't be added? If apps can be added to apps as well as pages, the end result might not look different at all?

Comment: There are different types of apps. Ones that you go to and install and apps that you can add to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Page is a like an open group.  It can to used to form a group for public figure or to form some open group like "StackOverflow lovers" etc, where you a creator acts as a admin, and there are discussion boards(to discuss an issue), events(to organize an event), notes(to create some document for page), photos (to create album).

And regarding Facebook App have two things Profile page and Application page, it is a Profile page of the Facebook App which looks similar to Facebook page which gives you information about the App. Well, if you want to go to Application page Click on "Go to App".